# Logstash - Parsing and mutating JSON file

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash

Having the following JSON file:

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "status": {"partial": true},
  "records": [
    {
      "info": {
        "startTime": "2016-07-17 08:42:40.212+0000",
        "endTime": "2016-07-17 08:43:47.715+0000",
        "id": "123456789"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "lines": [
          {
            "time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000",
            "text": "Hi There",
            "user": "user A"
          },
          {
            "time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000",
            "text": "Hello",
            "user": "user B"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "info": {
        "startTime": "2016-07-18 08:42:40.212+0000",
        "endTime": "2016-07-18 08:43:47.715+0000",
        "id": "4567890"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "lines": [
          {
            "time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000",
            "text": "Hi There",
            "user": "user X"
          },
          {
            "time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000",
            "text": "Hello",
            "user": "user Y"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT (raw format):

```
{"count": 20,"status": {"partial": true},"records": [{"info": {"startTime": "2016-07-17 08:42:40.212+0000","endTime": "2016-07-17 08:43:47.715+0000","id": "123456789"},"conversation": {"lines": [{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000","text": "Hi There","user": "user A"},{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000","text": "Hello","user": "user B"}]}},
{"info": {"startTime": "2016-07-18 08:42:40.212+0000","endTime": "2016-07-18 08:43:47.715+0000","id": "4567890"},"conversation": {"lines": [{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000","text": "Hi There","user": "user X"},{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000","text": "Hello","user": "user Y"}]}},
{"info": {"startTime": "2016-07-18 08:42:40.212+0000","endTime": "2016-07-18 08:43:47.715+0000","id": "4567890"},"conversation": {"lines": [{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000","text": "Hi There","user": "user X"},{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000","text": "Hello","user": "user Y"}]}},
{"info": {"startTime": "2016-07-18 08:42:40.212+0000","endTime": "2016-07-18 08:43:47.715+0000","id": "4567890"},"conversation": {"lines": [{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000","text": "Hi There","user": "user X"},{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000","text": "Hello","user": "user Y"}]}},
{"info": {"startTime": "2016-07-18 08:42:40.212+0000","endTime": "2016-07-18 08:43:47.715+0000","id": "4567890"},"conversation": {"lines": [{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000","text": "Hi There","user": "user X"},{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000","text": "Hello","user": "user Y"}]}},
{"info": {"startTime": "2016-07-18 08:42:40.212+0000","endTime": "2016-07-18 08:43:47.715+0000","id": "4567890"},"conversation": {"lines": [{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000","text": "Hi There","user": "user X"},{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000","text": "Hello","user": "user Y"}]}},
{"info": {"startTime": "2016-07-18 08:42:40.212+0000","endTime": "2016-07-18 08:43:47.715+0000","id": "4567890"},"conversation": {"lines": [{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000","text": "Hi There","user": "user X"},{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000","text": "Hello","user": "user Y"}]}},
{"info": {"startTime": "2016-07-18 08:42:40.212+0000","endTime": "2016-07-18 08:43:47.715+0000","id": "4567890"},"conversation": {"lines": [{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000","text": "Hi There","user": "user X"},{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000","text": "Hello","user": "user Y"}]}},
{"info": {"startTime": "2016-07-18 08:42:40.212+0000","endTime": "2016-07-18 08:43:47.715+0000","id": "4567890"},"conversation": {"lines": [{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000","text": "Hi There","user": "user X"},{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000","text": "Hello","user": "user Y"}]}},
{"info": {"startTime": "2016-07-18 08:42:40.212+0000","endTime": "2016-07-18 08:43:47.715+0000","id": "4567890"},"conversation": {"lines": [{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000","text": "Hi There","user": "user X"},{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000","text": "Hello","user": "user Y"}]}},
{"info": {"startTime": "2016-07-18 08:42:40.212+0000","endTime": "2016-07-18 08:43:47.715+0000","id": "4567890"},"conversation": {"lines": [{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000","text": "Hi There","user": "user X"},{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000","text": "Hello","user": "user Y"}]}},
{"info": {"startTime": "2016-07-18 08:42:40.212+0000","endTime": "2016-07-18 08:43:47.715+0000","id": "4567890"},"conversation": {"lines": [{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000","text": "Hi There","user": "user X"},{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000","text": "Hello","user": "user Y"}]}},
{"info": {"startTime": "2016-07-18 08:42:40.212+0000","endTime": "2016-07-18 08:43:47.715+0000","id": "4567890"},"conversation": {"lines": [{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000","text": "Hi There","user": "user X"},{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000","text": "Hello","user": "user Y"}]}},
{"info": {"startTime": "2016-07-18 08:42:40.212+0000","endTime": "2016-07-18 08:43:47.715+0000","id": "4567890"},"conversation": {"lines": [{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000","text": "Hi There","user": "user X"},{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000","text": "Hello","user": "user Y"}]}},
{"info": {"startTime": "2016-07-18 08:42:40.212+0000","endTime": "2016-07-18 08:43:47.715+0000","id": "4567890"},"conversation": {"lines": [{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000","text": "Hi There","user": "user X"},{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000","text": "Hello","user": "user Y"}]}},
{"info": {"startTime": "2016-07-18 08:42:40.212+0000","endTime": "2016-07-18 08:43:47.715+0000","id": "4567890"},"conversation": {"lines": [{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000","text": "Hi There","user": "user X"},{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000","text": "Hello","user": "user Y"}]}},
{"info": {"startTime": "2016-07-18 08:42:40.212+0000","endTime": "2016-07-18 08:43:47.715+0000","id": "4567890"},"conversation": {"lines": [{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000","text": "Hi There","user": "user X"},{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000","text": "Hello","user": "user Y"}]}},
{"info": {"startTime": "2016-07-18 08:42:40.212+0000","endTime": "2016-07-18 08:43:47.715+0000","id": "4567890"},"conversation": {"lines": [{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000","text": "Hi There","user": "user X"},{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000","text": "Hello","user": "user Y"}]}},
{"info": {"startTime": "2016-07-18 08:42:40.212+0000","endTime": "2016-07-18 08:43:47.715+0000","id": "4567890"},"conversation": {"lines": [{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:32.533+0000","text": "Hi There","user": "user X"},{"time": "2016-07-17 08:42:36.533+0000","text": "Hello","user": "user Y"}]}}
]}
```

I would like to use logstash to import `conversation.lines` (ignoring the rest of the information like `info`) for each of the records, and maybe run some logic like removing some of the lines depending on the time property.

Is it possible to do that with Logstash alone, or should I preprocess the file?

Comment: Are those JSON docs on a single line or are they pretty-printed as shown above?

Comment: each doc is a line, not pretty-printed but the first line contains the count and status fields

Comment: Can you show how the JSON data **exactly** looks like in the file you want to process?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, please see my edits

Comment: Ok, the JSON is actually spread over three lines, correct? How many JSON documents do you have in your file?

Comment: That was just an example, the real doc count is 3393

Comment: But each doc is spread over three or more lines?

Comment: Just the first , see my edits again

Comment: I don't get it :-) Can you show the first 20 lines from your file please?

Comment: I have duplicated the lines to better explain the format (i can't expose the real log)

Comment: ok, you're aware that this is a **single** JSON document, not several, right? so all you need to do is to parse it and create one ES document per `conversation.lines` in the `records` array, correct?

Comment: I'm aware of that, I need to parse it then create a document for each line in conversation.lines array, with some logic that decides if to create that record

Comment: How big is your file? I think the easiest would be to use node.js, though. `require` the file, loop over the records, loop of the conversation lines, apply your logic and send to ES with the JS ES client

Comment: So, currently I'm building a nodeJS tool, that will import that json format to elasticsearch. I was wondering if Logstash is the tool for the job. Do you recommend that I use Node for the entire process?

Comment: Logstash is good at parsing text files line by line, but if you want to parse a multi-line JSON file, that's not my first choice.

Comment: cool, please answer so I can accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest would be to use node.js.

1. `require` your JSON file
2. loop over the `records`
3. loop over the `conversation.lines`
4. apply your logic
5. send each line to ES with the JS ES client

Logstash is very good at parsing text files line by line, but if you want to parse a multi-line JSON file, that would not be my first choice.